# Get Height of UIImage inside UIimageView *aspectFill

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UITableView` with the `tableView.backgroundView` containing a `UIImage`. I am trying to attain the height of the image once it is set in the `imageView` - `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. Then I will `tableView setContentInset` to whatever the height of the image is so the entire image is in view.

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yValue, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 100)];

coverImageView = backView.frame;
coverImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
coverImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[backView addSubview:coverImageView];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backView; 

[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(coverImageView.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0)];
```

This understandably gives me the `imageView` height. I am unsure how to get the image height with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`